# Solr index built fast with SortedMapBackedCache returning document results with database column values missing

Tags: django, solr, dataimporthandler

.I have two tables in my Django app:
Product and Merchant

Merchant is a foreign key in Product.

Here's a snippet of my data-config.xml:

```
<entity name="products_product"
        query="SELECT id, merchant_id, product_id, retail_price, date_created FROM products_product"
        transformer="script:generate_resource_uri">


    <entity name="merchant"
            query="SELECT merchant_name, commission, commission_type FROM products_merchant"                    
            cacheKey='id' cacheLookup='products_product.merchant_id'
             cacheImpl="SortedMapBackedCache">
        <field column="merchant_name" name="merchant_name"/>
        <field column="commission" name="commission"/>
        <field column="commission_type" name="commission_type"/>
    </entity>
</entity>
```

And my schema.xml is [here](http://pastebin.com/6npjSyNV)

Problem is, that

```
cachePk="id" cacheLookup="${products_product.merchant_id}"
                    cacheImpl="SortedMapBackedCache"
```

does not work as expected. The index building time is reduced, because already fetched queries are taken from cache, **but** I'm not getting these fields in results:

```
merchant_name, commission, commission_type
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: do you see any suspicious thing in logs?

Comment: @AnkitPopli yeah.
`294905 [qtp865058941-11] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter  – Loading DIH Configuration: data-config.xml
294911 [qtp865058941-11] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.config.DIHConfiguration  – id is a required field in SolrSchema . But not found in DataConfig`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including the "id" column of your "merchant" entity in the SELECT query? as you are specifying that it will be the key to match with the lookup key.

```
<entity name="merchant"
        query="SELECT id, merchant_name, commission, commission_type FROM products_merchant"                    
        cacheKey='id' cacheLookup='products_product.merchant_id'
         cacheImpl="SortedMapBackedCache">
    <field column="merchant_name" name="mer`enter code here`chant_name"/>
    <field column="commission" name="commission"/>
    <field column="commission_type" name="commission_type"/>
</entity>
```